# Advertisements not showing in my approved app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

My first app has been approved at last. My app in the simulator runs fine. It shows the banner ads the way it is supposed to and the app was working fine as usual. Now, it has been approved and I have waited for 4 days and there are still NO banner ads to be shown. I know you are supposed to enable the ads on iTunes Connect, but I heard that it was no longer required. I'll post my code below and you guys can tell me what I did wrong.

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError(NSError *)error{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Also, I dragged an `ADBannerView` to the `ViewController` and linked it as "delegate" as well.

In my view controller.h, I have:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate> {
}
```

So, pretty much that's my code and I have no idea what is happening. I know you have to wait, but it's been more than 4 days already and I'm worried something happened. Also when sending it for review, I ticked "third party content" and selected NO for the "does this app use the advertising identifier (idfa)"

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are tying to use iAd, and may have missed this, from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a):

> iAd App Network will be Discontinued
>
> January 15, 2016
>
> The iAd App Network will be discontinued as of June 30, 2016. Although
>   we are no longer accepting new apps into the network, advertising
>   campaigns may continue to run and you can still earn advertising
>   revenue until June 30. If you’d like to continue promoting your apps
>   through iAd until then, you can create a campaign using iAd Workbench.
>   We will continue to keep you updated, but if you have any questions,
>   [contact us](http://developer.apple.com/contact/).

It displays at the top of the page as soon as you log into iTunesConnect.

Comment: Wait, so no more ads are going to come? :(

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. My app was approved two months back. It still show any iAds on my app. I think its because apple iAd network is shutting down on 30th june 2016. I got an email today from Apple.

> You are receiving this email because you entered into the Developer Advertising Services Agreement (“Agreement”) to use iAd’s advertising network and related services. We would like to thank you for allowing Apple to serve ads on your mobile properties. As you may know, the iAd App Network and related advertising services will be discontinued on June 30, 2016. More details about the iAd App Network shutdown are here. Note: Any outstanding payments due from Apple will be made no later than September 30, 2016, and campaign reporting data will be available until December 31, 2016.
>   This email shall serve as written notice that Apple will exercise its option to terminate the Agreement, effective June 30, 2016, 11:59 pm PDT. Nothing contained in, or omitted from, this notice shall be deemed a waiver of any of Apple’s rights, remedies or defenses, all of which are expressly reserved.
>   Regards,
>   The App Store Team